# Group by and count values by dayofweek DataFrame Spark SQL

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've loaded a DataFrame. It looks like this:

```
uber_converted.show()

+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+----------+---------+--------------------+
|dispatching_base_num|         pickup_date|affiliated_base_num|locationID|     zone|             borough|
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+----------+---------+--------------------+
|              B02765|2015-05-08 19:05:...|             B02764|       262|Manhattan|      Yorkville East|
|              B02765|2015-05-08 19:06:...|             B00013|       234|Manhattan|            Union Sq|
|              B02765|2015-05-08 19:06:...|             B02765|       107|Manhattan|            Gramercy|
|              B02765|2015-05-08 19:06:...|             B02765|       137|Manhattan|            Kips Bay|
|              B02765|2015-05-08 19:06:...|             B02765|       220|    Bronx|Spuyten Duyvil/Ki...|
|              B02765|2015-05-08 19:06:...|             B02765|       138|   Queens|   LaGuardia Airport|
|              B02765|2015-05-08 19:06:...|             B02749|       143|Manhattan| Lincoln Square West|
|              B02765|2015-05-08 19:06:...|             B02765|       244|Manhattan|Washington Height...|
|              B02765|2015-05-08 19:06:...|             B02617|       262|Manhattan|      Yorkville East|
|              B02765|2015-05-08 19:06:...|             B02765|       144|Manhattan| Little Italy/NoLiTa|
|              B02765|2015-05-08 19:06:...|             B00381|       209|Manhattan|             Seaport|
|              B02765|2015-05-08 19:06:...|             B02765|       234|Manhattan|            Union Sq|
|              B02765|2015-05-08 19:06:...|             B02765|       163|Manhattan|       Midtown North|
|              B02765|2015-05-08 19:06:...|             B02765|       181| Brooklyn|          Park Slope|
|              B02765|2015-05-08 19:06:...|             B02765|       116|Manhattan|    Hamilton Heights|
|              B02765|2015-05-08 19:06:...|             B02765|       236|Manhattan|Upper East Side N...|
|              B02765|2015-05-08 19:06:...|             B02765|       140|Manhattan|     Lenox Hill East|
|              B02765|2015-05-08 19:07:...|             B02765|       162|Manhattan|        Midtown East|
|              B02765|2015-05-08 19:07:...|             B02788|       263|Manhattan|      Yorkville West|
|              B02765|2015-05-08 19:07:...|             B02765|       181| Brooklyn|          Park Slope|
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+----------+---------+--------------------+
```

And I need to group and count by day of the week with the pickup_date field. the result must be like this

```
dayofweek   count
1         -> 234 (Monday)
2         -> 343 (Tuesday)
```

etc...

Any help, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `date_format`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format

df.groupBy(date_format(df["pickup_date"], "u").alias("dayofweek")).count()
```

Comment: great reply thank you. can you tell me how much parameters can i to use aside from "u"?

Comment: don't worry, here is the list [link] (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.htm)